# In the vue project created through vue-cli3, the ctrl + v feature of monaco-editor is invalid

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, vue-cli-3

i have created a vue project through cli3 (3.1.1 verion).And i installed monaco-editor(0.14.3).But in my page,the ctrl +v feature is invalid.
Here is my code:

```js
<template>
  <div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
export default {
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  mounted () {
    this.editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
      value: [
        'function x() {',
        '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
        '}'
      ].join('\n'),
      language: 'sql'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

so what is the problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: Tip: Don't use id, use ref! Did you add monaco webpack plugin to vue.config.js?